# Laravel error por favor ayuda

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas tardes. estoy trabajando en una aplicación en **laravel** y me sale el siguiente Error:

```
 ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\app-
 shop\resources\views\home.blade.php)
```

[image: Imagen del error]
[image: Linea del error]
[image: Estas son las rutas que tengo]

Como puedo solucionarlo gracias.

Comment: Podrias poner algo de código, por ejemplo donde te da el error, mas que nada para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Como dice @Spidvmp, mostranos el codigo tanto del archivo blade como del controller. pero seguramente estas llamando una propiedad en blade de un objeto que es null.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: ya pude solucionarlo solo con refresh :php artisan migrate:refresh --seed

Answer (score 0):

Lo importante acá es entender qué es esa variable $detalle que le estás pasando a la view desde el controller.

A simple vista te diría que el error se da al llamar el product, que asumo es una relación con detail: `{{ detail->product->featured_image_url }}`

Quizás cambiando esa línea por lo siguiente lo solucione: `{{ detail->product->first()->featured_image_url }}`

Tendrías que agregar el first() cada vez que llamas a product del modo en que lo estás haciendo, que veo que lo haces varias veces.